# How to optimize/simplify heapsorting django objects? (can't use modules and db sorts)

Tags: python, django, sorting, optimization, django-rest-framework

I have to ask for some help with an assignment I got as a test for a django internship. I had to make and imaginary api with rabbits and their carrots. Each rabbit was supposed to have a number of carrots, but the api had to be designed to allow for easy addition of other kind of vegetable. I rejected integer field for each vegetable and instead went for vegetable object with type and value of vegetable.

Problem is, the assignment also included listing the rabbits sorted by carrots, descending. They wanted me to implement heapsort, no database sort was allowed, no external libs. While i had no problem with that, I am having trouble with time constraints they thought of - for 20 000 rabbits to be sorted in under 30 seconds, ideally 5 seconds. And it already takes 5 seconds with 200 rabbits(just sorting and serializing to json).

I make a queryset that has only rabbits with "carrots" vegetables. Then I force it into normal list and run heapsort function on it.

How would I need to change it to be faster? Is it even possible? I will be very happy if someone helps even a bit. Thank You in advance!

My models:

```
class Bunny(models.Model):
    """Bunny model for bunny usage"""
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + str(list(self.vegetables.all()))

    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50)
    userAccount = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def getVegetable(self, vegetableType):
        for vegetable in self.vegetables.all():
            if vegetable.vegetableType == vegetableType:
                return vegetable
        return False


class Vegetable(models.Model):
    """Vegetable model for storing vegetable counts"""
    def __str__(self):
        return self.vegetableType + ":" + str(self.value)

    vegetableType = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=vegetableChoices)
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    bunny = models.ForeignKey(Bunny, related_name="vegetables", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My heapsort function:

```
def heapsort(bunnies, vegetableType):
    """Heapsort function for bunnies, works in place, descending"""

    for start in range((len(bunnies) - 2) // 2, -1, -1):
        siftdown(bunnies, start, len(bunnies) - 1, vegetableType)

    for end in range(len(bunnies) - 1, 0, -1):
        bunnies[end], bunnies[0] = bunnies[0], bunnies[end]
        siftdown(bunnies, 0, end - 1, vegetableType)
    return bunnies


def siftdown(bunnies, start, end, vegetableType):
    """helper function for heapsort"""
    root = start
    while True:
        child = root * 2 + 1
        if child > end:
            break
        if child + 1 <= end and bunnies[child].vegetables.get(vegetableType=vegetableType).value > bunnies[
                    child + 1].vegetables.get(vegetableType=vegetableType).value:
            child += 1
        if bunnies[root].vegetables.get(vegetableType=vegetableType).value > bunnies[child].vegetables.get(
                vegetableType=vegetableType).value:
            bunnies[root], bunnies[child] = bunnies[child], bunnies[root]
            root = child
        else:
            break
```

And also the performance test they asked for(I do not know of a better way. Just creating bunnies takes a long time)

```
def test_20000_rabbits_performance(self):
    print("Creating bunnies")
    register20000Bunnies()

    print("Created bunnies")
    timestart = time()

    url = reverse("api:list", args=["carrots"])

    response = self.client.get(url)
    timeMeasured = time() - timestart
    print("Sorted. Took: " + str(timeMeasured))

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My view:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def bunnyList(request, vegetableType):
""" Displays heap-sorted list of bunnies, in decreasing order.
    Takes word after list ("/list/xxx") as argument to determine
    which vegetable list to display"""
    if vegetableType in vegetablesChoices:
        bunnies =
    Bunny.objects.filter(vegetables__vegetableType=vegetableType)
        bunnies = list(bunnies)  # force into normal list

        if len(bunnies) == 0:
            return Response({"No bunnies": "there is %d bunnies with this vegetable" % len(bunnies)},
                        status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

        heapsort(bunnies, vegetableType)
        serialized = BunnySerializerPartial(bunnies, many=True)
        return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("No such vegetable. Available are: " + ", ".join(vegetablesChoices))
```

Edit: just checked now, currently it takes 1202 seconds to sort... My machine is 2 core 1.86GHz, but still.

Edit2, new code:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def bunnyList(request, vegetableType):
""" Displays heap-sorted list of bunnies, in decreasing order.
    Takes word after list ("/list/xxx") as argument to determine
    which vegetable list to display"""
if vegetableType in vegetablesChoices:
    vegetables =  Vegetable.objects.filter(vegetableType=vegetableType).select_related('bunny')
    vegetables = list(vegetables)

    if len(vegetables) == 0:
        return Response({"No bunnies": "there is 0 bunnies with this vegetable"},
                        status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    heapsort(vegetables)

    bunnies = [vegetable.bunny for vegetable in vegetables]
    serialized = BunnySerializerPartial(bunnies, many=True)
    return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
else:
    raise serializers.ValidationError("No such vegetable. Available are: " + ", ".join(vegetablesChoices))
```

Updated heapsort:

```
def heapsort(vegetables):
"""Heapsort function for vegetables, works in place, descending"""

for start in range((len(vegetables) - 2) // 2, -1, -1):
    siftdown(vegetables, start, len(vegetables) - 1)

for end in range(len(vegetables) - 1, 0, -1):
    vegetables[end], vegetables[0] = vegetables[0], vegetables[end]
    siftdown(vegetables, 0, end - 1)
return vegetables


def siftdown(vegetables, start, end):
"""helper function for heapsort"""
root = start
while True:
    child = root * 2 + 1
    if child > end:
        break
    if child + 1 <= end and vegetables[child].value > vegetables[child+1].value:
        child += 1
    if vegetables[root].value > vegetables[child].value:
        vegetables[root], vegetables[child] = vegetables[child], vegetables[root]
        root = child
    else:
        break
```

My serializers:

```
class BunnySerializerPartial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Used in list view, mirrors BunnySerializerFull but without account details"""
    vegetables = VegetableSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Bunny
        fields = ("name", "vegetables")


class VegetableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Used for displaying vegetables, for example in list view"""
    class Meta:
        model = Vegetable
        fields = ("vegetableType", "value")
```

And queries from the toolbar:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "zajaczkowskiBoardApi_vegetable" INNER JOIN "zajaczkowskiBoardApi_bunny" ON ("zajaczkowskiBoardApi_vegetable"."bunny_id" = "zajaczkowskiBoardApi_bunny"."id") WHERE "zajaczkowskiBoardApi_vegetable"."vegetableType" = '''carrots'''


SELECT ••• FROM "zajaczkowskiBoardApi_vegetable" WHERE "zajaczkowskiBoardApi_vegetable"."bunny_id" = '141'
```

Second one duplicated 20 000 times

Comment: Can you show the view and how you call heapsort?

Comment: Of course. Thanks for interest!

Comment: Well, the obvious problem is that in your while loop you're querying the database again. So design your flow to get everything into python, sort and do serialization in the final step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the classic N+1 queries problem. You perform a single query to fetch all the bunnies, but then you go on to do `bunnies[child].vegetables.get(vegetableType=vegetableType)` for each bunny, which performs an additional query, and thus an additional database roundtrip, for each bunny. So you perform 1 query for N bunnies, plus around N queries to get all the vegetables (hence the N+1).

Database roundtrips are one of the most expensive resource available to web developers. While comparisons take somewhere in the order of nanoseconds, a database roundtrip takes in the order of milliseconds. Do ~20K queries and this will soon add up to take several minutes.

The quick solution is to use `prefetch_related('vegetables')` and exclusively use `bunny.getVegetable('carrot')` to get the carrot. `prefetch_related()` will perform a single query to get all the vegetables for *all* bunnies and cache them, so iterating `self.vegetables.all()` in `getVegetables()` won't perform any additional queries.

---

There are better solutions, though. In this case, it seems that each bunny should have at most 1 `Vegetable` object of a specific `vegetableType`. If you enforce this at the database level, you won't have to worry about errors in your sorting algorithm when someone decides to add a second `Vegetable` of type `'carrot'` to a bunny. Instead, the database will stop them from doing that in the first place. To do this, you need a `unique_together` constraint:

```
class Vegetable(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [
            ('vegetableType', 'bunny'),
        ]
```

Then, rather than fetching all bunnies and prefetching all related vegetables, you can fetch all vegetables of type "carrot" and [*join*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) the related bunnies. Now you will only have a single query:

```
carrots = Vegetable.objects.filter(vegetableType='carrot').select_related('bunny')
```

Since the combination of `vegetableType` and `bunny` is unique, you won't get any duplicate bunnies, and you will still get all bunnies that have some carrots.

Of course you'd have to adapt your algorithm to work with the vegetables rather than the bunnies.

Comment: I will try the quick solution when I can tonight, can You tell me how much could it improve the performance? If i understand it right, it would take half as much time? (Sorry for silly question, I should get my O-notation understanding straight). And big thank You for Your time.

Comment: @Nullbyte It should take the number of queries down from ~20K to 2. `prefetch_related` uses _one_ query to fetch _all_ vegetables for _all_ bunnies. It should make a tremendous difference: I'd expect it to take less than a second.

Comment: Oh my God this is amazing. Can't wait to try this out.

Comment: I did changes to my code, and I chose the better solution You provided. When testing I use APIClient get method and it measures 19 seconds, but when I use browser on developers server it still makes 20001 queries (inspected with django debug toolbar). I get bunnies in a way shown in edit, after sorting the vegetables. Why are bunny fields of vegetables not populated and require query? Does list call earlier in the view break it? Or the developer server or sqlite is not fit for this?

Comment: @Nullbyte Can you update the heapsort as well? What are those 20K queries fetching exactly?

Comment: Added heapsort code. If serialize sorted vegetables list and return it is executes nicely in 6 seconds. It must be list comprehension that queries for bunnies, as if select_related did nothing. Again, maybe it's developer server/sqlite related

Comment: @Nullbyte `vegetable.bunny` should already be cached by using `select_related('bunny')`. Can you check in django-debug-toolbar what the actual queries are? Can you share your serializer as well?