# Django ignores select_related, makes more requests to fetch related objects

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-rest-framework

I'm making django api for an internship application and run into optimization problem, and while my previous problem was almost fixed, i've run into related problem. The rest of my code and initial problem are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862777):

I'm using select_related as can be seen here in my view:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def bunnyList(request, vegetableType):
""" Displays heap-sorted list of bunnies, in decreasing order.
    Takes word after list ("/list/xxx") as argument to determine
    which vegetable list to display"""
if vegetableType in vegetablesChoices:
    vegetables = Vegetable.objects.filter(vegetableType=vegetableType).select_related('bunny')
    vegetables = list(vegetables)

    if len(vegetables) == 0:
        return Response({"No bunnies": "there is 0 bunnies with this vegetable"},
                        status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    heapsort(vegetables)

    bunnies = [vegetable.bunny for vegetable in vegetables]
    serialized = BunnySerializerPartial(bunnies, many=True)
    return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
else:
    raise serializers.ValidationError("No such vegetable. Available are: " + ", ".join(vegetablesChoices))
```

This should perform only one query, but as i can see in django debug toolbar is making one + 200 other (one for each vegetable object) in list comprehension, as if it it is completely ignoring the join in the select_related query.

The performed queries are:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "zajaczkowskiBoardApi_vegetable" INNER JOIN "zajaczkowskiBoardApi_bunny" ON ("zajaczkowskiBoardApi_vegetable"."bunny_id" = "zajaczkowskiBoardApi_bunny"."id") WHERE "zajaczkowskiBoardApi_vegetable"."vegetableType" = '''carrots'''
```

And this one slighly modified for all objects:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "zajaczkowskiBoardApi_vegetable" WHERE "zajaczkowskiBoardApi_vegetable"."bunny_id" = '153'
```

Thank You for any help on resolving this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, `BunnySerializerPartial` needs to fetch all related `vegetables` for each bunny. 
So `select_related` is not enough, you should write:

```
vegetables = Vegetable.objects\
                      .filter(vegetableType=vegetableType)\
                      .select_related('bunny')\
                      .prefetch_related('bunny__vegetables')
```

This way, a second query will be executed to fetch all vegetables related to all selected bunnies.

Comment: Is there a different way? This lowers the number of queries to max 2, but can it ideally be one?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with django ORM. You might want to write a raw SQL query, but I don't think that would help: 2 joins would still be needed and you would potentially retrieve duplicated data (for example if 2 selected vegetables are linked to the same bunny, then all vegetables related to this bunny will appear twice in the results).

Comment: This solution is not enough, throws too many sql variables error on higher number of bunnies, query is enourmous

Comment: Maybe that's your view or serializers that should be modified then. The `BunnySerializerPartial` require all related (unfiltered) `vegetables`. If that's really what you want, they need to be retrieved anyway.

Comment: I want just the carrots, how would I need to change the serializer?